# Eclipse freezes Ubuntu, hard reboot required

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm on a team of 6 developers and we are all using Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 11.04. At least once a day, if Eclipse is running, each of us experiences a total system lock-up. The only cure is a hard reboot of the PC. Some of us have had it more than ten times in one day. This does not happen if Eclipse is not running, so I can confidently say that Eclipse is the problem.

I have tried increasing the memory available to Eclipse by going into the ecplise.ini and increasing the Permsize, MaxPermSize, Xms, and Xmx. This has made no difference and everyone's PC is still locking up.

Has anyone experienced this before? I could understand maybe on one PC, but it happens on every single PC!

- Java version: java-6-sun-1.6.026 JDK version
- Ecplise version: Indigo SR1 BuildID 20110916-0149
- Ubuntu version: 11.04 64-bit

EDIT: Ctrl-Alt-FnX keys do not work once the PC has locked up.

EDIT: I've revisited the eclipse.ini settings and increase the memory some more. So far I haven't had a crash yet. I will use the other developers as guinea pigs, but I'm hopeful that these settings will stop the crashing.

```
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Do you see anything interesting in eclipse logs? Look for them in  workspaceLocation/.metadata/.log . I have not had such problem with similar setup (except it was 32bit) so can not help right away.

Also do combinations Ctrl+Alt+FnX work when desktop freezes? 
And maybe it is worth trying to select different desktop variants (Ubuntu2d session or XFCE) to see if it affects the behaviour.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary as far as I can tell. Lots of !ENTRY messages, but I will open the log file again on the next crash and see if anything is recorded.

Comment: Also, do your desktops have same hardware configuration? Can it have something to do with video drivers?

Comment: You might try installing something like `psacct` to see if you can detect resource usage spikes … ? Or, can you tell if the lockup is due to ( killing X | running out of memory | overloading CPU )? If it's just killing X, you may be able to `ssh` in.

Comment: Petr: They do all have the same hardware config, yes. They are using Intel graphics chips.

Comment: BRPocock: I'll try running psacct. I cannot SSH to the PC once it has locked up though, sadly.

Comment: I had same issue on VM, than I have installed openJDK after. everything fine now.

Comment: We actually installed Sun Java thinking OpenJDK was the issue!

Comment: is it possible you have both x64 and x32 of java and eclipse not addressing to 64 bit java_home? is eclipse 64 bit indigo?

Comment: I know that this has long been answered, but I just wanted to add that the only way I've found to gracefully get out of this 'total eclipse lockup' is to hit Alt+SysRq+F and wait a few minutes for the Eclipse process to die.  I'm running 10.04LTS 64bit (which I plan on upgrading now 12.04LTS is out) and which still suffers from this issue to this day...

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 has the same problem. I figured out that it is somehow related to contextual menu, when ever I am trying to right click and call context menu, the problem appears exactly as described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrading the kernel to the latest version. I think this lock up is caused by the kernel bug detailed on this page https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/924905

Comment: Great Scott, I think you've cracked it! My kern.log looks almost identical to the bug you've linked to. I am going to upgrade the kernel on my machine tomorrow and see if this solves the problem. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I followed my own advice and upgraded my kernel. It has fixed the problem for me. This time last week, my box was locking up several times a day, but it hasn't locked up once in the last five days (since I did the upgrade).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to do it on my box yet, but I am highly confident that this will solve the issue. I hope report back next week and mark your response as the solution.

Comment: Eureka! We've run an entire week without freezing. Thank for your solution, Chris.

Answer (score 6):

This is not to resolve Eclipse problem... which might be happening because of some display issues I suspect.

Instead of hard reboot you can press keystrokes `Ctrl+Alt+F1` together to reach console and there you can login to a text based terminal and kill the Eclipse process.

Comment: I've tried to do that, but the entire system is unresponsive. Not even the old Alt+SysRq+REISUB trick works.

Comment: If entire system doesn't respond then you can `remote SSH` to your host and kill the Eclipse process.

Comment: SSH does not respond, unfortunately. The PC is totally locked up.

Comment: Hmm in that case, after reboot check what `/var/log/messages` file shows when system froze.

Comment: Wow. If even ssh does not work then likely this is not one of the problems I suspected (graphics, X11 or desktop). However I doubt that Eclipse can lock system to that extent. If you are positive that it is caused by Eclipse then problems could be related to native libraries (SWT). I once had problem with inaccessible system when Xorg config was wrong. But then system was unusable from start.

Comment: @PetrGladkikh I am observing the same thing, have been using my Ubuntu 14.04 vm without a freeze for a year. First time I open up eclipse, the whole vm becomes completely unresponsive.

Answer (score 5):

more a comment than an answer, but I cant add you a comment yet.

I'm kinda using the same setup: Ubuntu 11.04 64bit with Eclipse Indigo SR1 RC3 64-bit (buildid 20110909, didnt had time or need to update to a newer release yet, but RC3 is stable for me). Make sure, you have installed the 64-bit version of Eclipse.

- OpenJDK in combination with Eclipse didnt went well for me, so I changed to java-sun jdk 1.6/7. Make sure Eclipse is not referencing to the OpenJDK installation instead of java-sun jdk.
- I had some issues with Eclipse Indigo (pre SR1) freezing in combination with SVN Subversive/m2eclipse plugins. For me it got better with the SR1 (RC3), but still not perfect (a freeze now and then). A while later Subversive SVN had an update, and now it's stable again. In short: make sure, you have installed the newest plugin versions (use eclipse update sites, no local copies). Older versions might lead to the same problems I experienced.
- What other plugins are you using, can you verify if your Eclipse crashes without any plugins installed?
- Two other issues I'm aware of: with Ubuntu Karmic Koala (9.10) rendering UI elements was broken/lead to crashes as well (GTK_NATIVE_WINDOWS). Later Eclipse had problems with the native scrollbars (think it was with Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04). I'm pretty sure, problem 1 aint an issue anymore with Eclipse Indigo + 11.04. Problem 2 I'm not sure if it was 10.10 or 11.04. But I still start my eclipse with the following script.sh and it works for me, you could give it a shot as well:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
  export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=false
  exec $(dirname $0)/eclipse "$@"
  ```

Comment: If SWT architecture does not match (if you use 32bit instead of 64bit) then eclipse will not start at all. But the problem that Eclipse works somehow so this is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I wasnt aware of that. Since I run other programs which are not supported on 64bit Linux either (Lotus Notes), I thought it could be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed some graphical fragments for me.

Answer (score 4):

While you wait for better answers, I would definitely try a virtual machine like Virtual Box to:

1. Try to see if I can replicate the problem in a Virtual environment, which is similar to your actual environment. This way you can see if the problem the combination of the versions of software that you're using or your physical hardware.
2. Run Eclipse through the VM. It may not crash and will prevent you from having to do a full re-boot of the system, until you determine what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem. From time to time it happens that the complete X11 desktop freezes. I can still move the mouse but clicks on elements have no effect.
In this situation I switch to the text console and kill eclipse. After I did that, everything works again.
I am using a laptop with an Intel graphics chipset. So I tend to blame it on the the graphics driver.
I have other computers with different graphics hardware where I haven't noticed the problem, but I don't use eclipse that often on them. On all I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64bit with gnome or unity desktop.

Comment: Your situation sounds very similar to mine. The only difference is that I cannot get to a text console as the keyboard is unresponsive. We are getting a new PC for one of the team members in a couple of weeks, so this will hopefully give us an answer.

Comment: I have the same problem, to switch to text console press ctrl+alt+f1 and ctrl+alt+f7 to switch back to your desktop

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues. It is very inconvenient. I have just confirmed  that killing eclipse fixes the issue for me.

However, I have found something strange in that I can still click on the stupid overlay scrollbars. It's like they have the focus of the entire system.

What seems to have fixed the issue to me was to install the gnome shell and start using gnome 3, then turn off the overlay scrollbars in the startup scripts for X. I installed gnome 3 for a separate reason and disabled the scrollbars because I find them annoying, but I do find that this has solved the problem for me. You may be able to get away with just disabling the scrollbars, information for which is readily available on google.